# Change color of box to random array element on an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

Hello I have made this peace of code in order to change the color of a box, when ever the mouse enters it's area. there is an event on mouseenter and i have made a function which should return a random color from an Array. It does not seem to work.

```
$("#colorBox1Id").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", SelectRandomColor) 
});


function SelectRandomColor() {
    var colorArray= new Array("blue", "red", "yellow", "green");
    var selectedColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random*colorArray.length)];

    return selectedColor;
}`
```

I hope someone has a suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: you forgot the brackets when calling random, it should be Math.random()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)];`

```js
$("#colorBox1Id").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", SelectRandomColor)
});


function SelectRandomColor() {
  var colorArray = new Array("blue", "red", "yellow", "green");
  var selectedColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];

  return selectedColor;
}
```

```css
#colorBox1Id {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colorBox1Id">
  Colorbox
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `Math.floor(Math.random() * (colorArray.length + 1))` for perfectly even distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `random`.

```
var selectedColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)];
                                                     ^^
```